# Update to VS ver 2012 - 11.0.50727.1 errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We recently upgraded to 2012 Visual Studio 11.0.50727.1 (update 5).  We need to keep 2012 because in later versions, the C# statements do not work (like **obj["Click"] ()**).

So when I brought it up I got a message that SccProviderPackage did not load correctly (see image).  IT said I could probably ignore this, as it is not used.

But then when I opened my projects there was a problem.  I can still see the Solution Explorer on the right (see image).  But on the left where there used to be the tests I can run there is nothing.  Not even a menu.  I looked through the View menu to see if there was a way to show it, but I could not find anything.

Could this be a problem from that error, or some other kind of error?

BTW this is on Windows 10.
[image: missing tests]
[error loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMYeV.png)

Comment: "because in later versions, the C# statements do not work" Can you elaborate on this, and include specific code that shows that? You can change the C# version of your project at any time, the editor you're using shouldn't matter.

Comment: yes, it doesn't like the syntax such as  obj["method"]();  It appears to want a newer (and in my opinion better) format like obj.method();  All our code is written in the former style.

Comment: Are you sure that's not a change in ASP.Net, or some other framework, rather than C# syntax? I don't believe c# _ever_ allowed you to reference a method on an ordinary object via an indexer.

Comment: In fact, that looks more like Javascript syntax, TBH.

Comment: Something occurred to me: this MIGHT have been allowable syntax in Classic ASP, which could use either javascript or VBA on the server side. You're not talking about _that_ , are you?

Comment: Also, the image you refer to does not appear in the question.

Comment: You really might want to consider updating the platform your software is running on. If you are constrained to VS 2012, the number of security fixes you are missing in the accompanying runtime is nothing short of terrifying.

Comment: Sorry about the pictures.  I think they are there now.  One of them shows right away.  It looks like for the other you need to click "Error Loading".  And yeah, when I look at Smart Bear examples for accessing Test Complete through C# it gives examples as Javascript/C# so it lumps them both together

Comment: What _edition_ of VS 2012 are you on? is it possible you're now running a version that doesn't expect to include test support? Like, Developer but not Professional, something like that?  (Don't remember what the different versions are: 2012 was a long time ago!)

Comment: Visual Studio 11.0.50727.1 (update 5).

Comment: Visual Studio is just an editor. It does not generate error messages or directly compile code. VS utilizes the .Net framework to do the compiling, building and reporting of warnings/errors. Remove VS from the mix by compiling your project from the command line. Most likely what happened is that the version of .Net got an update which fixed issues and now your build is reporting these issues. Sticking to a version of C#/.Net because of some syntactic sugar is a poor excuse for accumulating technical debt.

Comment: When I brought up the new version on  a different machine it asked what env I would like to set up for (C#, C++, other compilers).  I looked through the menus to see how to tell it to use C# but I couldn't find anything.  Do I need to re-setup for C#?  If so, do you know where I would do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do a Ctrl + E, T to get the menu to appear

[image]